# Cx_Oracle and Pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller, cx-oracle

I've packaged an executable using pyinstaller and it works fine on my machine. However, when I share the executable and try to run it on another machine and the apps tries to run a query the following error message is returned:

ora-12154 tns could not resolve the connect identifier specified

I am assuming that oracle service as specified is not listed in TNSNAMES.ORA on the target machine.   Has anyone found a way to include this in the pyinstaller executable creation or is that even an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use TNSNAMES.ORA with cx_Oracle, you can specify a full connection string instead. That would remove the dependency if that works for you.

If there is some reason you have to use TNSNAMES.ORA then you could include a utility with your application to find the file and add an entry to it. Py installer does allow you to bundle files with your application using --add-data but I don't think you would be able to put TNSNAMES.ORA in the right location using this method (and if you could it would overwrite the existing file which could be annoying for your users)

Comment: The cx_Oracle 8 [`init_oracle_client()`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#optional-oracle-net-configuration-files) function could be used in the app to give the location of the tnsnames.ora file if you do bundle it.  Or you can simply use an Easy Connect string, see the cx_Oracle doc: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connection-strings

Answer (score 0):

Using the code below as part of my connection string worked on the same machine that was giving the ora-12154 error message.

import cx_Oracle

CONN_INFO = {
'host': 'xxx.xx.xxx.x',
'port': 12345,
'user': 'user_name',
'psw': 'your_password',
'service': 'abc.xyz.com',
}

CONN_STR = '{user}/{psw}@{host}:{port}/{service}'.format(**CONN_INFO)

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(CONN_STR)